# Simulate keyboard buttons to use Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")

Tags: android, input, unity-game-engine

I've been stuck on this for a while and I would appreciate your help.

I need to port a game to mobile devices and as a result I need to change the control scheme to take into account taps.

I want to keep using Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") since the game was built and balanced around it, and just simulate a left/right keystroke whenever a player taps on the left/right side of the screen.

Is that in any way possible?

**onUpdate:**

```
touchMove()
 playerPosition.x += Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * playerVelocity;
 transform.position = playerPosition;
```

**To check taps**

```
private void touchMove()
     {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0)
         {
             Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

             if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2)
             {
                 //simulate a left keyboard push
             }
             else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2)
             {
                   //simulate a left keyboard push
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate your own value depends on how far from the middle screen your touch is and Multiply it depends on how far the touch?

Comment: I am trying to just call Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") (or a similar method) whenever the user taps left/right of the screen. GetAxis works fine for me since it has smoothing attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just added a force to simulate movement and drag to simulate decceleration. It's a very good alternative to getAxis.

I need to tweak my code some more, but this should work well for both keyboard and touch inputs.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems it is not possible to have a script who set values to Input.

As a replacement, you can use your own middle function who gets into account whatever you want.

Example :

```
private int GetAxisHorizontal()
{
    // Get whatever should return your axis value
    if(Input.touches > 0) {... return value;} 
    else return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}
```

And you can use it like your normal function :

```
playerPosition.x += GetAxisHorizontal() * playerVelocity;
```

Comment: Yea I agree that it's not trivial to simulate inputs. See my below answer for what I did to resolve this issue. 

Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I did what r3x did, and [this](http://pastebin.com/VGtnSP6f) is my player script now. It has Mobile and Keyboard Controls, and a built-in multiple bindings options (change `KeyBindings` class).

http://pastebin.com/VGtnSP6f

(Code thing is still kinda buggy)

EDIT: Just want to note that a lot of this script is getting the keys/mouse position and lerp-ing it to make it smooth. Make the `/ 40f` Lower to increase smoothing.